# how to match element which starts with a prefix using element.matches?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some html elements on the dom which have an id which starts with a prefix.
e.g

```
<div id="Prefix_START_31231231323" style="display:none"></div>
<div >some more stuff</div>
<div id="Prefix_END_31231231323" style="display:none"></div>
```

I need to match the Html elements whose id starts with

> Prefix_START or Prefix_END

so that i can exclude them while processing.

I tried using `element.matches('#^Prefix_START');`
but this doesn't work.

Is there a way to do this partial match ?

Answer (score 2):

You mean !element.matches

```js
const notPrefix =[...document.querySelectorAll("div")]
  .filter(ele => !ele.matches("[id^=Prefix]"));

console.log(notPrefix)
```

```html
<div id="Prefix_START_31231231323" style="display:none"></div>
<div >some more stuff</div>
<div id="Prefix_END_31231231323" style="display:none"></div>
```

Alternatively you can do querySelectorAll and filters to narrow more

```js
const ele323 =[...document.querySelectorAll("[id^=Prefix]")]
  .filter(ele => ele.id.endsWith("323"))

console.log(ele323)
```

```html
<div id="Prefix_START_31231231323" style="display:none"></div>
<div >some more stuff</div>
<div id="Prefix_END_31231231323" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` for the prefix as part of the attribute value:

```
attribute*="...value..."
```

In this case, there will be a selection of elements for specific parts *START* and *END*, the value of the attribute `id`, alternating with selectors.

```js
let matches = document.querySelectorAll('[id*="START"], [id*="END"]');
matches.forEach(match => {console.log(match)});
```

```html
<div id="Prefix_START_31231231323" style="display:none"></div>
<div >some more stuff</div>
<div id="Prefix_END_31231231323" style="display:none"></div>
```